# Appending content dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, amcharts

I use javascript to display a series of charts (graphs) one under the other. The Javascript script requests data from a PHP script then draws the charts and displays it. It doesn't take much time to fetch data for one chart and diplay it but with many charts the time accumulates which is boring. I would like to display the first chart when it is ready and then the second chart etc. so user sees how those get dynamically appended on the page making the page longer and longer.

Basically here is what I have:

```
<script>
var i=0;
$.getJSON('stats.php', function (data) {
    for (chartData in data) {
        i++;
        var chart = new AmStockChart();
        dataSet.dataProvider = chartData;
        // etc. etc.

        $('#stats').append('div id="chartdiv' + i + '"></div>');
        chart.write("chartdiv" + i);
    }
});
</script>

<div id="stats"></div>
```

That produces about 10 graphs one under the other but the problem is that shows empty screen for about 3-5 seconds and then displays all the graphs at once. If I limit it to diplay only one graph it shows up much faster. It would be nice to show those graphs gradually one by one when each graph is ready.

**UPD:** Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbKSa/10/) I put test data and cycled through one graph 20 times.

Comment: actually that 3-5 sec is for fetching the data.Once its fetched its displayed.Anywaz can create a jsfiddle for ur code

Comment: Ok, just added jsfiddle to post

Comment: ok..just added an answer with demo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thing along the lines of this should help.....

```
var i = 0;
$.getJSON('stats.php', function (data) {
    for (chartData in data) {
        i++;
        setTimeout(function(index,d1){
            return function() {
                  var chart = new AmStockChart();
                  dataSet.dataProvider = data[d1];
                  // etc. etc.

                  $('#stats').append('div id="chartdiv' + index + '"></div>');
                  chart.write("chartdiv" + index);
            }
        }(i,chartData), 3000*i);
    }
});
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fbKSa/16/)

Comment: Hm... I feel this is very close, but this one appends empty divs all with the same id

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, that's probably how it should be. However I started to put that on my code which has several graphs in the array and found out that your demo put out only last graph for all the time. I have modified the jsfiddle example and added two graphs to the array. Your can see it here[link](http://jsfiddle.net/fbKSa/14/) that only last graph gets repeated.

Comment: This is genius! So the data fetching time is what it takes to show the first graph, and the rest are showing with 3 sec delay each, right?